# What is the use of () post require() in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I understand `require()` is used to import a particular node module into another and use it. But what is the use of using additional `()` post that. Say i have following require statement in my `server.js` file : `var init = require('./config/init');`. It just means that we are importing modules declared in `./config/init.js` file. But what does `var init = require('./config/init')();` mean ? What is the use of **()** at the end of `require` statement ?

Comment: When the module you're requiring exports a function, putting `()` after the require will invoke the function.

Comment: Example: `const express = require('express'); const app = express();` vs `const app = require('express')();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply that if this line imports a `function` :

```
var init = require('./config/init')
```

...then the additional `()` executes that function immediately.

Think of it as shortcut for these 2 lines

```
var initLib = require('./config/init')
var init = initLib();
```

Answer (score 1):

`require('library')` returns the *exports* of the specified library. In this case, it looks like the library returns a function, and you're simply calling that and storing the value returned from the function.

In this case the module you're importing has code like this:

```
module.exports = function() {
    ...
    return theInitValue;
}
```